# KenKen Puzzle Helper - Dropping order-less sequences

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, puzzle

In the following example, I am generating all the variants of a $9 \times 9$ [*KenKen*](http://www.kenkenpuzzle.com/#) puzzle that come in groups of three using addition that result in $18$.

```
  data = Select[Tuples[Range[9], 3], Plus @@ # == 18 &]
```

This generates

$\{\{1,8,9\},\{1,9,8\},\{2,7,9\},\{2,8,8\},\{2,9,7\},\{3,6,9\},\{3,7,8\},\{3,8,7\},\{3,9,6\},\{4,5,9\},\{4,6,8\},\{4,7,7\},\{4,8,6\},\{4,9,5\},\{5,4,9\},\{5,5,8\},\{5,6,7\},\{5,7,6\},\{5,8,5\},\{5,9,4\},\{6,3,9\},\{6,4,8\},\{6,5,7\},\{6,6,6\},\{6,7,5\},\{6,8,4\},\{6,9,3\},\{7,2,9\},\{7,3,8\},\{7,4,7\},\{7,5,6\},\{7,6,5\},\{7,7,4\},\{7,8,3\},\{7,9,2\},\{8,1,9\},\{8,2,8\},\{8,3,7\},\{8,4,6\},\{8,5,5\},\{8,6,4\},\{8,7,3\},\{8,8,2\},\{8,9,1\},\{9,1,8\},\{9,2,7\},\{9,3,6\},\{9,4,5\},\{9,5,4\},\{9,6,3\},\{9,7,2\},\{9,8,1\}\}$

I can then do something to search for repeated cases without order

```
  Cases[data, {OrderlessPatternSequence[1, 8, 9]}]
```

This generates (I want to delete all those after $198$ from data, but to do it for each unique set of three digits).

$$\{\{1,8,9\},\{1,9,8\},\{8,1,9\},\{8,9,1\},\{9,1,8\},\{9,8,1\}\}$$

This approach has two drawbacks, I had to know the sequence to test for, then I can use that to drop all the repeats from data. I would have to repeat this for the next unique sequence.

Is there a simple way to create

```
 data2 = some_fancy_command[data]
```

It produces data2 (note - I don't care about the commas either), which only has unique 3-digit numbers regardless of order

$$\{\{189\},\{279\},\{288\}\},\{369\},\{378\}\}... $$

What is the easiest way to do that?

Note that I am familiar with https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/478684/, but only want a helper as opposed to a solver.

Aside: My goal is to have a tool that effectively duplicates [https://homepages.bluffton.edu/~nesterd/apps/kenkenhelp.html](https://homepages.bluffton.edu/%7Enesterd/apps/kenkenhelp.html) as maybe a CDF of just an MMA Notebook where I enter all the cages, their type, the size of the puzzle and it provides hints on all the numbers that can go into the cage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
triples = Select[Sort /@ IntegerPartitions[18,{3},Range[9]], DuplicateFreeQ]

FromDigits /@ triples
(* {189, 279, 369, 459, 378, 468, 567} *)
```

If you allow repeated numbers then:

```
FromDigits@*Sort /@ IntegerPartitions[18, {3}, Range[9]]
(* {189, 279, 369, 459, 288, 378, 468, 558, 477, 567, 666} *)
```

Comment: That is perfect! Will this do all plus, minus, multiply, divide for any length?

Comment: No this is just plus, also it's missing 288, but I assume that's a mistake in your question because the 8s aren't unique.

Comment: We can have cages that allow repeated numbers - they just won't show up in the same column or row. The same rules as Sudoku puzzles where there is a unique number in each row and column, but cages can span one or more rows or columns.

Comment: No need for the `AllTrue` and `nrange` nonsense. Use the arguments of `IntegerPartitions`...
Never mind - looks like you updated your answer.